# Is there a way to reorder a dataframe's column using a user defined list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, swap

### Hi there heroes!

I'm currently working on a project where I have to process 2D arrays using pandas (numpy is out of question in the context for reasons I can't explain).

I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
pd.DataFrame(
{
    'some_id': [0, 0, 0, 0, 
                1, 1, 1, 1, 
                2, 2, 2, 2],
    'some_name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
                  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
})
```

which yields something like so: ([example initial dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ9ro.png))

#### Now here is my problem:

I want to swap all the rows in a given column with another set of rows. For example, I want to change "some_id" order to `[2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` without losing the order in the other columns. Basically, I want to swap a list of rows with another list of rows. This would then be the [result after swapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBwcu.png) the initial dataframe using the list in this paragraph.

**I would also like to mention that the number of element containing the same value may differ. So the initial dataframe may look [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bviTN.png).**

Here's what I tried so far (none of them worked):

- pd.sort_values() --> Did not work since you can't pass a custom list of order.
- 

```
temp_val = df.loc[df['some_id'] == 0]
df.loc[df['some_id'] == 0] = df.loc[df['some_id'] == 1]
df.loc[df['some_id'] == 1] = temp_val
```

This solution seemed to work to find the right rows. however, it fails to swap rows and creates 'NaN' values on the whole row.

I'm sorry for posting so many images. I'm out of ideas and time is running on my side. Thanks peeps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom key to map the values you want in order, and leave the rest unsorted using stable sorting:

```
order = [2,1,0]
df2 = df.sort_values(by='some_id', kind='stable',
                     key=lambda s: s.map({k:v for v,k in enumerate(order)}))
```

output:

```
    some_id some_name
8         2         a
9         2         b
10        2         c
11        2         d
4         1         a
5         1         b
6         1         c
7         1         d
0         0         a
1         0         b
2         0         c
3         0         d
```

Comment: That's very clever! I'm not quite sure to grasp the whole map section though. You build a dictionary as I can see, but it maps the dictionnary how?

Comment: It constructs key/value pairs where the keys are in the defined order and the values are increasing integers from 0, try to run `order = ['B', 'A', 'C'] ; {k:v for v,k in enumerate(order)}`

Comment: Oh okay! So, each time the sort_value() function access a value, it uses the dictionnary to access the right Key. So if the first value is 'B', it will access 'B' value which is 0?

I'm starting to understand the dictionary part, but the nebulous part is: it works with numbers, but if my some_id column was full of, lets say [frame_0, frame_0, frame_1, frame_1, frame_2, frame_2], it wouldn't work in my head.

But it works and I dont quite get why.

Comment: It works with anything that is hashable. And no, the mapping is not done for each value during the sorting, but once at the beginning. Slight difference for performance ;)

Comment: Oooh I think I got it. Basically the key act as a kind of mask where it uses the dictionary to  "make" a new column which will be made of the values under each key. If I take your example, every `B` and `A` and `C` will be respectively "turned" into `0`, `1`, `2` and THEN the sort will be done. After the sort, the values will be "turned back" to what they were, so `A`, `B` and `C`, but in the right order.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it (with some nuances, like the fact that there can be missing keys, etc.) ;)